# Override Classes With ClassName in Emotion

Tags: reactjs, emotion

How to override a css classes (css classes are generated randomly named from emotion) with className prop in emotion without important. React version is: "16.12.0", emotion version is "11.0.0"

```
<button
   css={theme => theme.button.style}
   className={"bertug"}
>
</button>
```

My theme style is;

```
const theme = {
   style: {
      color: "#fff"
   }
}
```

My class;

```
.bertug {
   color: "#000"
}
```

[image: Dev. Console apperance]

Comment: use color: "#000" !important

Comment: You can just add the style attribute to the button: `<button style={{ backgroundColor: #000000 }}></button>` if you want to override it.

Comment: It would overwritten by className not with important or inline style

Comment: Ah yea just checked the docs, it looks like you can use the css prop? https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop

Comment: I already used css. Class name is normal css, button style is object. We cannot use css class name like .bertug with css prop.